# How notification system works in Elementary OS 5?

Tags: notifications

I have a question about how notifications work in Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera.

I have multiple apps installed like Slack and Spotify and I really need to see the ones from Slack but want to hide those from Spotify.

By default when I install Spotify from flathub, there is Spotify icon in notification centre so I can suppress Spotify notifs. The strange thing is, that they also appear duplicated under "other" so I need to also disable notifications from all other apps.

Slack from flathub does not show in notifications until I edit `/home/tomasz/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/com.slack.Slack.desktop` and add `X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true`. That shows controls for Slack in notification center but even if I enable everything there, the notifications are still under "other" and I need to silence those to not get ones from Spotify.

What can I do to tell Elementary that this app produces those notifications so I can configure them properly? Are there any other magic lines `.desktop` files?